# PHP function mysql_connect() does not work if file extension is rewritten from html to php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have html file with php code in it. It contains code to connect to mysql database.

When i run it, it returns me an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: mysql_connect()
```

Everything works fine if file extension is php.

Also, just to mention that using `.htaccess` I have rewritten file extension.

Also some functions, like include and echo work fine.

Can you help me please how to handle this?

**Update:** Here is the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^item/(.*) item.html/$1
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) page.html/$1
RewriteRule ^page2/(.*) page2.html/$1
RewriteRule ^browse/(.*) browse.html/$1

RewriteRule ^(.*).txt /page/error.html

ErrorDocument 400 /page/error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /page/error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /page/error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /page/error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /page/error.html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.php3 index.htm index.html.var
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Comment: Can you share your .htaccess file?

Comment: This means the mysql_extension hasn't been loaded. Post your .htaccess.

Comment: Not that your problem is caused by this, but, mysql_connect is for a long time depreciated. Use mysqli & mysqli_connect instead.

Comment: @DMin 'deprecated' is a term with particular meaning, not applicable here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's server issue. hosting provider admit that it's their mistake.

Answer (score 1):

run phpinfo() in both files and see.
There will be 2 different versions of PHP.
Most likely your mysql-enabled version has a different handler, like application/x-httpd-php5 or something

Comment: you are right! there are two different versions of PHP. I will wait for support to get info what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

This means mod_mysql (MySQL extension) is not installed or was not loaded correctly on the Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out all offending lines of code until the script runs (even if with warnings and notices); drop a `phpinfo()` at the start, run the script and check out what `php.ini` is it picking up.

You may have a stray `php.ini` somewhere with the mysql extension commented out... If so, edit it to load the required **mysql** extension. If you find out that the **mysqli** extension is loaded instead, just change every *mysql_** function in your code to *mysqli_** and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding to htaccess...

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: web hosting issue, address to your support.